# Consulta en MySQL no muestra datos solo los encabezados de las columnas

Tags: mysql

Tengo la siguiente sentencia en `MySQL`:

```
select tblservicio.folio, tblservicio.Producto, tblServicio.Modelo, tblservicio.No_serie, tblservicio.Descripcion, tblservicio.estatus, tblcliente.nombre_cliente, tblcliente.telefono, tblcliente.correo, tblcliente.Direccion, tbldiagnostico.descripcion, tbldiagnostico.requerimientos, tbltecnico.nombre, tblusuario.nombre_u, tblentrega.Fecha_entrega 
from tblservicio 
inner join tblcliente on tblservicio.fk_cliente = tblcliente.no_cliente 
inner join tbldiagnostico on tblservicio.folio = tbldiagnostico.no_diagnostico  
inner join tbltecnico on tblservicio.fk_tecnico_asignado = tbltecnico.rfc_tecnico 
inner join tblusuario on tblservicio.fk_usuario = tblusuario.rfc_usuario 
inner join tblentrega on tblservicio.folio = tblentrega.fk_servicio;
```

El problema es que se ejecuta pero no muestra los datos de los campos seleccionado solo muestra el nombre de las columnas. Alguien podría decirme porque o ayudarme a solucionarlo, de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 2):

El por qué es sencillo: porque no hay ningún registro que cumpla con todas las condiciones que le impones al conjunto de productos internos (INNER JOIN) que planteas. Si MySQL te muestra los nombres de los campos es que la consulta está correctamente construida, sin errores de sintaxis, ni nombres de campos o de tabla erróneos. Simplemente no hay datos que cumplan tus requisitos.

Para ayudarte más, tendrías que enviarnos el SQL de tu base de datos (en phpMyAdmin, opción Exportar) con algún dato de muestra, qué datos esperas obtener de tu consulta (a partir de esos datos de muestra) y el SQL de las consultas que hayas intentando, para poder detectar el error y orientarte sobre cómo resolverlo.

Bienvenido a SO y espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Gracias, ciertamente el problema estaba en los datos, me faltaban datos que eran las llaves foraneas por lo tanto no había relación en las tablas.

Comment: Genial, me alegra que hayas dado con ello. No te olvides de marcar la pregunta como respondida para evitar que entre más gente a intentar responderla y vota si lo crees oportuno :) También puedes responderte a ti mismo y dejar constancia de la solución, por si a alguien le pasa algo similar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer